# Invalid modifier in string for command unset "\C-;"

Tags: key-bindings

The command `(global-unset-key "\C-;")` fails with the message: `Invalid modifier in string`.

Perhaps because of the special character `;`. What is the proper way to unset this key?

Any other normal character works, e.g.: `(global-unset-key "\C-c")`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"\C-;"` is not an ASCII character.

Try `(global-unset-key (kbd "C-;"))` or `(global-unset-key [?\C-\;])`.

See the Emacs manual, node [Init Rebinding](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-Rebinding.html):

> When the key sequence includes function keys or mouse button events,
>   or non-ASCII characters such as `C-=` or `H-a`, you can use a vector to
>   specify the key sequence...

See also the Elisp manual, node [Ctl-Char Syntax](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Ctl_002dChar-Syntax.html).

Comment: BTW, the vector representation is `[?\C-\;]`.

Comment: @xuchunyang: Yes, I was typing that while you commented. ;-)

Comment: The first one works: `(global-unset-key (kbd "C-;"))`.